# How to output from multiple lists? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to output each Show with their times, however I get that for loop does each show four times with each time. How do I solve that, so I get a show from the channelList, start time form channelStartTime and end time from channelEndTime?

```
def main():
    print("TV Schedule")
    print()
    channelList = []
    channelStartTime = []
    channelEndTime = []
    finished = False
    channel = input("Which channel are you entering the schedule for?: ")
    date = input("What date is the schedule for? (MM/DD): ")
    print()
    print("To exit press ENTER")
    while not finished:
        show = input("Please enter the name of the show: ")
        if len(show) == 0:
            finished = True
        else:
            startTime = input("What time does the show start?: ")
            endTime = input("What time does the show end?: ")
            channelList.append(show)
            channelStartTime.append(startTime)
            channelEndTime.append(endTime)

# Schedule display
    print()
    print("{0} schedule for {1}".format(channel, date))
    print()
    print("{0:<15} {1:<5}-{2:<5}".format("Show", "Start", "End"))
    print()
    for eachShow in channelList:
        for eachStart in channelStartTime:
            for eachEnd in channelEndTime:
                print("{0:<15} {1:<5}-{2:<5}".format(eachShow, eachStart, eachEnd))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip()` the lists together so that we'll see a start and end for each one:

```
for eachShow, eachStart, eachEnd in zip(channelList, channelStartTime, channelEndTime):
    print("{0:<15} {1:<5}-{2:<5}".format(eachShow, eachStart, eachEnd))
```

Previously you were looping for every start and end time, even the ones not relevant to the current show.  You may find better usability out of a dictionary for this type of data structure in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to iterate over all the items of a list, for all other items of all the other lists. You should iterate at the same time:

```
for show, start, end in zip(channelList, channelStartTime, channelEndTime):
    print(show, start, end)
```